# How can i get a list of currently running threads in objective-C(iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, multithreading, nsthread

Is there a way to get the list of currently running threads in objective-C?
I'm mostly interested in getting the NSThreads objects, cause i want to replace the assertion handler for each running thread?

If such thing is not possible, maybe i could set my own selector to be invoked after any thread is spawn(so that i could do the assertion handler replacement over there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[Assertions and Logging Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Assertions/Tasks/UsingCustomAssertHndler.html)" says you can only set the assertion handler for the current thread:

> You must execute these steps in the
>   thread which you wish to modify; one
>   thread cannot modify the thread
>   attributes dictionary of another.